# Title of Minimized Application in Ubuntu - Where does it come from?

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, gnome, xlib

When an application is running in Ubuntu, it displays an icon in the top left corner and also a title - "Terminal" when terminal runs, "Files" when file manager. For my app it shows "Unknown". I want to change that.

I inspected properties of the File Manager, and the word "Files" is not there. The name of the File Manager's Window is "Home".

I inspected the org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop file and it does have a line "Name=Files". But similarly, my app has such line in its *.desktop file.

Where does Ububtu (Gnome) takes the name which it displays in top left corner?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: WM_CLASS property contains the name of the .desktop file which contains the information used by Ubuntu. Found this information here:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/ApplicationBased

Comment: You can also specify path to .deskop file in `_NET_WM_DESKTOP_FILE` property - see my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/530376/association-window-desktop-file-launcher-entry/530431#530431